# Usage of the word "Friday"

Tags: terminology

**Summary:**
Is the usage of the word "Friday" to refer to released/old software or requirements something widely used and if so: is there a definition and/or reasoning behind this terminology?

**Longer version:**
At my current workplace, some formal requirements are written in the form 'High-level description of some functionality', followed by "See Friday Functionality".

From context, I understand that this requirement refers to an existing functionality in already released software (from the same company) that solves the same high-level problem. I have also heard similar usage in meetings, such as: "Friday requirements", "Friday solution" or "Friday software".

Since I haven't heard it before I have tried to search with Google and asking the persons that use this terminology in meetings to find out if this is internal jargon or something widely used and preferably get a formal definition (since it is used in requirements). My success so far has been lacking.

Comment: I never heard that.

Comment: I have never heard it either.  My first guess is that it's a product name or a code name for a product.  Or the formal requirements were pushed up against a hard deadline, and some informal notes found their way into the phrasing of the formal requirements.  I could see having referred to a meeting that occurred on Friday, or a version of the requirements that were released on the previous Friday.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thank you for the suggestion. If you read the question you will see that I already tried that.

Comment: Can you tell us what answer they gave you?  Did they refuse to answer? I don't understand why you didn't get a proper answer to your question, unless your coworkers are so disrespectful that they chose not to answer you.

Comment: @RobertHarvey They confirmed what I already gathered from context, that they are referring to [actual name of older product]. The persons who wrote the original requirements are not with the department anymore so there is sometimes more guessing than knowledge.

Comment: Then that's what it means.  It's a code name for an older product,  nothing more than that.

Comment: Damn, the usual suspects have put this question on hold before I could post my answer. So posting it in these comments: Phrases around poor results from Friday work are common, at least in my experience, eg "You bought a Friday car" for [one that breaks down a lot](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Friday%20car). Also as we all (should) know, [deploying on a Friday is a bad idea](http://perrymitchell.net/article/why-friday-deployments-are-a-bad-idea/), not least because folk want to get home for the weekend, leading to poorer quality. [1 of 2]

Comment: [2 of ] 
Both productivity and quality declines noticeably on Fridays compared with other days of the week. [This is well researched and documented](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=friday+productivity+study).

Comment: @DavidArno: I've been doing this for a very long time, and this is the first I've ever heard of the expression.  The real question is, should we be using this site as a forum for every random word that someone doesn't understand in his workplace?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, fair point. This should have been closed as off-topic, inviting the OP to post on [English language and usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/). Voting to close it as opinion-based wasn't helpful.

Comment: @RobertHarvey You mean "their workplace". Also: I am sorry if I misjudged the situation. From my point of view this came up in very formal documents that companies might form contract disagreements over and since it was hard to find a definitive answer by googling I thought that if this was a term used outside my current workplace it might be useful in the future on the site.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize you were female.  I was using the word "his" in the generic sense.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, your company *should not* be using terms like this in formal documents or contracts unless they specifically define such words in the document preamble.

Comment: If you search for "friday functionality" you will find that at least one Canadian company uses the term as if they expect any reader to understand what they are on about.

Comment: @MartinMaat: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Friday%20car

Answer (score 0):

This probably derives from the "Friday Car" used for cars which had lots of problems in the belief it was built on Friday afternoon when all the factory workers were thinking of going home for the weekend.